# Возможность остановить анимацию css

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-animation

Здравствуйте!

Есть ли возможность остановить анимацию css с той позиции, когда нажата кнопка Pause и снова запустить с места остановки

На данный момент при `checked Pause` - анимация сбрасывается

Решение на javascript есть. Хотелось бы решение на css.

Код [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kma5zknu/)

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play+label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]~.progress:after {
  animation: animProgress 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

Comment: Занимался этим вопросом, у меня не получилось. Пришлось уйти в js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лови.

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play + label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play + label[for=play] > span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked + label[for=play] > span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked + label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked + label[for=play] > span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation: animProgress 7s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#play ~ .progress:after {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#play:checked ~ .progress:after {
  animation: animProgress 7s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

p.s. В примере выставил один цикл.

Comment: Хорошее решение. Respect.

Answer (score 3):

Поменял немного ответ Kniha m. Добавил цикличность в анимацию. Так как было у автора.

```css
#play {
  display: none;
}

#play+label[for=play] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #37A000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#play+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2),
#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play] {
  background: tomato;
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
}

.progress {
  height: 15px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  width: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #37A000;
  animation: animProgress 7s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;  
}

#play:checked+label[for=play]~.progress:after {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes animProgress {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="play" id="play">
<label for="play">
  <span>Play</span>
  <span>Pause</span>
</label>

<div class="progress"></div>
```