# Анимация в css, псевдоклассы css, приостановка кода js

Tags: javascript, css

У меня вопрос:

Я использовал псевдокласс `:activate` для старта анимации (`.b-menu:activate{`), возникла проблема: анимация проигрывалась, но ТОЛЬКО когда пользователь зажимал кнопку, мне же нужно, что бы он один раз нажал (не зажал, а именно нажал и отпустил) и анимация проигралась.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Код:

```
 @keyframes menu{
10%{
position: relative;
bottom: 24px;
transform: rotate(36deg);}
20%{
position: relative;
bottom: 48px;
transform: rotate(72deg);}
30%{
position: relative;
bottom: 72px;
transform: rotate(108deg);}
40%{
position: relative;
bottom: 96px;
transform: rotate(144deg);}
50%{
position: relative;
bottom: 120px;
transform: rotate(180deg);}
60%{
position: relative;
bottom: 144px;
transform: rotate(216deg);}
70%{
position: relative;
bottom: 168px;
transform: rotate(252deg);}
80%{
position: relative;
bottom: 192px;
transform: rotate(288deg);}
90%{
position: relative;
bottom: 216px;
transform: rotate(325deg);}
100%{
position: relative;
bottom: 240px;
transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.b-menu:active{
animation: menu 0.7s;
}
```

Comment: Лучше код покажи... Все что выше описано, без проблем можно реализовать...

Comment: Хорошо. Добавил код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможность остановить анимацию css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768322/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-css)

Comment: Vadizar, эта тема отвечает только на 2 моих вопроса из 3. Остался последний вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли задать свой вопрос.
Но если я верно понял суть, то JS так-то не нужен в данном случае...
Атрибут `tabindex` + псевдокласс `:focus` = решение на одной лишь CSS.

```css
#container {
  display: flex; justify-content: space-around; 
  padding-top: 35px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; 
}

.test {
  flex: 0 0 100px; height: 100px; 
  background: linear-gradient(#ef4, #2a4); 
  transform: rotate(-180deg) translateY(-80%); 
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in; 
  outline: none;
}
.test:focus {
  transform: none; 
  transition-timing-function: ease-out; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="test" tabindex="1"></div>
  <div class="test" tabindex="2"></div>
  <div class="test" tabindex="3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: отличный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Через добавление класса. 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pm412oz/9/)

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");

div.onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("bottom");
};
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .3s;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: -50px;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```